# Django created_by and modifed_by admin site issue

Tags: python, django

I create created_by and modified_by fields in my abstract model.
Django Version: 1.4.3
Python Version: 2.7.3
According with documentation I created my abstract class:

```
# base.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('userdata.Profile',
                                   related_name=
                                   '%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by',
                                   default=1)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey('userdata.Profile',
                                    related_name=
                                    '%(app_label)s_%(class)s_modified_by',
                                    default=1)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I inherit this model in all my models about 50 models.

syncdb - OK
south - OK
runserver - OK

I look on my tables by SQLite Manager and everything looks fine.

I login into admin site and open any of my tables and I get:

```
Traceback:
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  366.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  196.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1233.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  85.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in iterator
  291.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in results_iter
  763.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  818.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  40.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "I:\xxx\virtualenvs\fff-2\lib\site-packages\django-1.4.3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  344.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/userdata/address/
Exception Value: at most 64 tables in a join
```

My question is: Can you see any mistakes on this example?
My question 2: Is it SQLite limited to 64 joins? and on Postgres it will be fine?

EDITE:
Yes, this happend when I open list view any model in admin panel.
I removed created_by and modified_by from all list_displays. Didn't help either on local mashine with SQLite and on Server with Postgres

All tests are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to removed every single relation from list_display not only created_by and modified_by. Then create new colummns in view like in example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('level', 'description', '_parent', '_created_by',
                    '_modified_by')

    def _parent(self, obj):
        return "%s" % obj.parent

    _parent.short_description = 'Parent'

    def _created_by(self, obj):
        return "%s" % obj.created_by

    _created_by.short_description = 'Created By'

    def _modified_by(self, obj):
        return "%s" % obj.modfied_by

    _modified_by.short_description = 'Modified By'
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed Sqlite3 limits the number of join to 64 tables as the [doc](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) points out. It's most likely that with other database engine you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) says they are limited to a max of 64 joins.

Which admin view are you on when this happens? I'm assuming it is list view?

You could ignore your two foreign key fields on the list display by  manually specifying which fields to display in the admin using

[`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)